# Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setBounds'

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to do my own custom classes and learn C and Objective C. I'm recieving the error that there is an incompatible type for argument 1. I've defined a struct and class like this:

```
typedef enum {
 kRedColor,
 kGreenColor,
 kBlueColor
} ShapeColor;


typedef struct {
 int x, y, width, height;
} ShapeRect;


@interface Shape : NSObject
{
 ShapeColor  fillColor;
 ShapeRect   bounds;
}

- (void) setFillColor: (ShapeColor) fillColor;
- (void) setBounds: (ShapeRect) bounds;
- (void) draw;

@end // Shape
```

Then I import the Shape.h file(code above) and try and create a shape like this:

id shapes[4]; // I'm different!

ShapeRect rect0 = { 0, 0, 10, 30 };
 shapes[0] = [Shape new];
 [shapes[0] setBounds: rect0];

I get the error that setBounds is incompatible. For some reason it isn't looking at the Shape.h class for the setBounds method and it is instead looking at the default setBounds method? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Learn Objective-C on the Mac by chance? I am having the same problem.

Comment: btw it was an "incompatible type for argument" compilation error

Answer (score 3):

If there is another method called `setBounds:` then using type `id` will usually result in the compiler picking the first encountered `setBounds:` (for determining return types and argument types), and since yours probably not the first, it is giving the error. You either need to tell the compiler that you want to use *your* `setBounds:` by changing the type from `id` to `Shape *`, but you can also cast your `id` to a `Shape *` and it should work also:

```
[(Shape *)shapes[0] setBounds:rect0];
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code, `shapes[0]` is just an `id`, for which the compile does not know there is `setBounds:`.
Instead, you should declare `shapes` as

```
Shape* shapes[4];
```

By the way, if you had an error, please post exactly what error was spit out by the compiler, not just saying '... was incompatible', because there are many ways in which a thing can be incompatible! Writing it down explicitly would help people here answering your question, because that way we don't have to guess exactly what has happened. Eventually, you yourself would become able to understand from the error message what is going wrong.